# How to draw a table inside first quadrant?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, graphics, graphs

I want to draw a table inside first quadrant. For example[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:
[image]

with this code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[-latex] (0,0)--(6,0) node[pos=.5,below] {\bfseries Order};
        \draw[-latex] (0,0)--(0,6) node[pos=.5,xshift=-7pt,rotate=90] {\bfseries Energy};
        \draw (1,1) rectangle (5,5);
        \draw (1,3)--(5,3);
        \draw (3,1)--(3,5);
        \draw (2,4) node () {\large \bfseries A};
        \draw (4,4) node () {\large \bfseries B};
        \draw (2,2) node () {\large \bfseries C};
        \draw (4,2) node () {\large \bfseries D};
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: To answer to your comment I propose this code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 \;\\
\;\\

\vspace*{1cm}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
            \draw[-latex] (0,0)--(6,0) node[pos=.5,below] {\bfseries Order};
            \draw[-latex] (0,0)--(0,6) node[pos=.5,xshift=-7pt,rotate=90] {\bfseries Energy};
            \draw (3,3) node () {\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                    \hline
                    A & B \\
                    \hline
                    C & D \\
                    \hline
            \end{tabular}};
    
        \end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{document}
```

with this output:

[image]

You have to adapt the coordinate (3,3) to suite your table.

Comment: @darkphysics Did You like my answer?

Comment: @Raffele Santoro I was actually looking for the diagram in the first quadrant as a table not as a rectangle since I am planning to replace with some other kind of table.

Comment: I was actually looking for the diagram in the first quadrant as a table not as a rectangle since I am planning to replace with some other kind of table.

Comment: See my edit adapted to yours comments.